# Are square of a maximal ideal and a maximal ideal coprime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $I, J \subset R$ be different maximal ideals. Is it true that $I^2$ and $J$ are coprime?

It is well known that $I$ and $J$ are coprime seen by the fact $I + J$ is an ideal containing $I$ and $J$. Attempting the same strategy, we get $I^2 + J = R$ or $J$. Therefore what we want to show is that $I^2 \not\subset J$. I am stopping here.

I am not specialized in algebra. Should you tell me the fact around this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This approach is also alright, you just need to note that if $I^2\subset J$, then $I=J$. This is true since $I$ is maximal and $J$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment using maximal $\Rightarrow$ prime ideal. Now I can see things from different angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I^2$ and $J$ are coprime. Since $I + J = R$, There exist $x \in I$ and $y \in J$ satisfying $x + y = 1$. Then, $1 = (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. Since $x^2 \in I^2$ and $2xy + y^2 \in J$, we have $1 \in I^2 + J$. Therefore $I^2 + J = R$.

Comment: This is just an appreciation of the argument on the extension for Chinese remainder theorem. I should have thought more. It seems to me that I am tired now.

Comment: If you have things you want to add, your answer is still welcome. I will wait for around one day.

Answer (score 1):

It even works for noncommutative rings. Since maximal ideals are prime, $I^2\subseteq J$ would imply that $I\subseteq J$, and that would mean $I=J$, but you assumed they were different maximal ideals.  Ergo, $I^2\nsubseteq J$, and $I^2+J=R$.

Comment: This strategy is same as what Alex’s comment pointed out. But thanks anyway.